# Default value on new window form

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I've an issue with bad default value in CRM.
I create new Activity in CRM (Technical Visit) and when new window is appearing I get value which is incorrect. Even business rule doesn't help, because that value appears when Subject field is empty. After typing anything and saving - it disappears.

For better view - have a look at this:

[I mean this value :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BSIH.png)

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing "Nouveau Visite technique" translates as "New Technical Visit".

In which case this is just the behaviour of CRM. Once you set a value in your record's primary name field (i.e. sujet/subject) then that will be shown instead. As far as I know this can't be customised, its just the way it works.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that "Nouveau Visite technique" is translated to Fr from Eng :). 
There is no way to correct that? Even by plugins? I was digging in all of entities, but cannot find this.

Comment: I believe it's meant to be like that so the user knows they are working on a new record, I don't think there is anyway to change that.